# Solution Folders in VS2008 are Not Alphabetized

Tags: visual-studio-2008, solution, alphabetized

I moved a bunch of projects to Solution Folders to chop up our list of projects into manageable folders, now each of the folders projects are not in alphabetical order. This only occurs on machines other than my own. Any ideas how to alleviate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the following bug information on MS Connect: 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=312252&wa=wsignin1.0

To summarize:
"
The order they show up in solution explorer is the order in which they were written to the solution file.   However, if the folder is collapsed on startup it will be sorted when you expand it.
"

Therefore, the fast solution would be to hand edit the solution file and put the projects in the order you wish.

Comment: I reopened a new issue here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=380287, still no answer... This is a bummer... I'm getting fed up with F2/Enter

Comment: @Benjol: I confirmed validation and marked it as important on ms connect.  Maybe they will actually fix it.  It can't be that hard to do a sort on load.

Answer (score 7):

I actually did hand edit the solution file and it didn't work (yea it was like 175 projects!) haha. But if you load the solution and then right-click and rename any file, without actually renaming of course, and then click off the solution will magically alphabetize.

Answer (score 3):

I found a tool that seems to do the trick:
http://solutionsorter.codeplex.com/